# Truncating and overwriting a table as a strategy for periodic updates

Tags: mysql, architecture

I am wondering about the performance and architectural downsides of overwriting a table completely with every (infrequent) update.

Due to some odd requirements, a MySQL database is currently acting as the store for a GraphQL API. It has no foreign key constraints and no other fancy features, and has a meaningless primary `INT` key. I am currently working on a script that populates it with slow-updating data, effectively one human-readable text file per row.

My concern is that with new text files, the generated primary keys will naturally change, and that people might want to query against them via the API. I don't want to keep track of IDs in the text files and *`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`* the table.

Simply scanning every text file and truncating the table to then re-populate seems both easy and efficient, but is there a better way or something I might run into with this method? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good practice to abstract the primary key away from the consumers of your API - it warrants another column in your table like `file_index`. Decoupling the data from the index will also help separate database maintenance issues from the API issues / development.

As for possible pitfalls, it's best to avoid deleting and/or updating data whenever possible. Not that it's a bad idea, but it introduces complexity that should be justified by the functionality it provides.

In general, a more complex solution is workable but will require a greater time investment in development and (especially) testing to be as robust as a simpler alternative.

I would add a column like `file_index MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` without an index, and supply that value to my API consumers if they need a unique integer for each file.

Comment: Thank you for your response! The filename index was a good idea. I implemented both that and a system that looks for git commits and updates only changed entries accordingly. :)

Comment: You're welcome! Your update mechanism sounds elegant - I admire when someone builds "the right tool for the job" instead of slapping a boilerplate solution on the problem.